# Bandwidth limiter

Tags: internet, raspberry-pi, bandwidth

I am looking for software that will allow me to connect to a network wirelessly, limit it to a set amount, output said speed to Ethernet port.

The catch is I need said limit to be variable, easily. Almost like turning a knob up and down (metaphorically speaking). It just needs to be easily able to change.

Limits should be set client-side across all ports (i.e. per interface). And I'll need such a tool for Linux, Mac, and Windows clients.

Any OS. I can pay if needed. I have a Raspberry Pi b+ and 2 if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I've used is called NetLimiter. It doesn't cost all that much and you can get a trial. You can see what programs are using bandwidth (upload & download) and set limits on individual programs as well as globally throughout the entire computer. It has an easy to navigate GUI interface and it's being updated constantly.

## [NetLimiter](https://www.netlimiter.com/) (commercial)

> NetLimiter gives you full network control over your computer. You will decide where your application can connect and how fast these connections will be.
>
> - Full internet bandwidth control over applications and computers
> - Powerful connection blocker
> - Long-term internet traffic statistics
> - Fully customizable behaviour using user-defined Rules and Filters
> - And much more...
>
> [image: NetLimiter Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There is also NetBalancer by SeriousBit. It gives you the ability to set priorities on certain programs and gives the option to set limits globally on the entire computer too. It has a nice GUI interface and allows a trial & free upgrades.

## [NetBalancer](https://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/) (commercial)

> NetBalancer is an internet traffic control and monitoring tool designed for Microsoft Windows XP, 2003, Vista, 7, 8 with native x64 support.
>
> With NetBalancer you can:
>
> - Set for any process a download and/or upload network priority or limit
> - Manage priorities and limits for each network adapter separately
> - Define detailed network traffic rules
> - Group local network computers and balance their traffic synchronised
> - Set global traffic limits
> - Show network traffic in system tray
>
> [image: NetBalancer Screenshot]